# jQuery onclick delayed timeout for each tile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**http://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/XJMgYX**

Hi, I have a grid of products. And I have a tooltip that appears on each respective grid item when you click the green add button. This tooltip will automatically disappears after 3 seconds, unless you click the add button again ultimately resetting the timeout. Thus keeping the tooltip visible for a longer time.

Now this works fine when you only do it on one tile. However when you go over to the next tile and click the add button during the timeout of the previous tile the tooltip of the previous stays visible forever, which is not intended. I want it to disappear as well.

Is there anyway to have the timeout work as intended regardless of which add button you click?

Thank you

```
$purchasePlus.on('click', function(){

var $confirmationBadge = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.tile__promotion');
$confirmationBadge.addClass('flip');
clearTimeout(timer);   
timer = setTimeout(function(){
    $confirmationBadge.removeClass('flip');
},1500);        


$(this).css({
    'min-width':'40px'
}).addClass('tile__animate').html('+');
var $text = $(this).siblings().find('.purchase--input');
$text.val(parseInt($text.val(), 10) + 1);
setTimeout(function() {
    $text.removeClass('focus');
}, 2000);
if($text.val() > 1) {
    $text.addClass('focus');
    $(this).siblings().find('.purchase--input').addClass('focus');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way but you could check to see if the current target is the same as the previous target. If it is, clear the interval. If it's not, set the `previousTarget` as the current one:

```
if(e.target == previousTarget){     
    clearTimeout(timer);   
}else{
    previousTarget = e.target;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qErjzX)

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time to help. Your solution is close but even when you click the plus button whilst alternating between two tiles they still go revert back to the red tooltip. Is there anyway to recode it? Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianGraz can can explain this some more? I'm not sure I understand